# footnotebackref conflict with amsart when footnote inside something labled is used

Tags: footnotes, amsart

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
    1=1\footnote{1}
\end{equation}
\ref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

This produces an error because the label of the equation is overwritten:
[image]

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{cleveref} %I get wrong hyperlinks with and without cleveref
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\makeatletter
\edef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}
\xpretocmd{\@adminfootnotes}{\let\@makefntext\BHFN@OldMakefntext}{}{}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{@makefnmark}
    {}
    {%
     \renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
       \mbox{%
         \textsuperscript{%
           \normalfont
           \hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}%
         }%
       }\,%
     }%
     \BHFN@OldMakefntext{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\footnote{Test1}

\begin{align}\label{eq:1}
    1=1\protect\footnotemark
\end{align}

Test\footnotetext{\label{fn2}This is footnote} eq.~\ref{eq:1}
%\cref{fn2}
\end{document}
```

gives an output that LOOKS alright, but the backref from the second footnote hyperlinks to the first footnote :( How can this be fixed? Did I implement [MadyYuvi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121024/madyyuvi)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523533/128042) wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package, and am sure it's never been tested with the AMS document classes.  But it's rather unusual to use a footnote *within* display math, and not generally recommended.  (Of course, if it's on `\text` in a display, that makes more sense, but ...)  Anyhow, this is something that should be reported to tech-support@ams.org so that they know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below `MWE` will help you:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\makeatletter
\edef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}
\xpretocmd{\@adminfootnotes}{\let\@makefntext\BHFN@OldMakefntext}{}{}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{@makefnmark}
    {}
    {%
     \renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
       \mbox{%
         \textsuperscript{%
           \normalfont
           \hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}%
         }%
       }\,%
     }%
     \BHFN@OldMakefntext{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{eq:1}
    1=1\protect\footnotemark
\end{align}

\footnotetext{This is footnote}\ref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

PS: Ideas borrowed from one of `egreg` post...

**Output**

[image]

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\makeatletter
\edef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}
\xpretocmd{\@adminfootnotes}{\let\@makefntext\BHFN@OldMakefntext}{}{}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{@makefnmark}
    {}
    {%
     \renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
       \mbox{%
         \textsuperscript{%
           \normalfont
           \hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}%
         }%
       }\,%
     }%
     \BHFN@OldMakefntext{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{eq:1}
    1=1\protect\footnotemark
\end{align}

Test\footnotetext{\label{fn1}This is footnote} eq.~\ref{eq:1}
\cref{fn1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I want to refer to a footnote using `cleveref` with your code, it doesn't work. Do you know how to fix this? When I write `\cref{footnote:1}` it produces "?? 1" instead of "footnote 1"

Comment: If you follow the `package` order, like `\usepackage{cleveref} \usepackage{footnotebackref}` then the said error won't happen...

Comment: Refer edits for better understanding...

Comment: for every `\protect\footnotemark` the backref is hyperlinked to another footnote?

Comment: Can you provide your `MWE`?  As I didn't face such issue...

Comment: @ MadyYuvi I added an `MWE` to my quetion